# Images are not Re-loading with User Control in wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, user-controls

I am using user control to show the data within the long list selector.
User control is having an image and two text blocks.
In the user control we are downloading images and assign source to image control asynchronously.
Assigning Long list selector source as Observable collection and binding user controls with properties except image control because here downloading images and assign source to image control at code behind.The above procedure is working fine for first time. I'm having refresh functionality, here making service calls and updating the Observable collection but here user control load event is not getting fired so here we are unable to assign images again so images are jumbling with existed items and this scenario happening with if there is no change in data. If i have any changes in observable collection then it's working fine because using of INotifyPropertyChanged.
I am searching since past 5 days but i didn't get solution.
If anybody help me on this issue highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a new collection on refresh click, then simply you can clear your `ObservableCollection` and fill it with new data. Then clear `longlistselector` `itemsource` and reassign it.

```
 RefreshButtonClick()
{
     _viewmodel.MyObservableCollection.Clear();
      MyList.ItemsSource.Clear();
    //fetch the observable collection data and assign to the list
}
```